# Javascript localStorage contact with checkbox

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a settings panel on which there is a checkbox that is responsible for auto-theme change on off. The first problem is that this checkbox does not allow to be changed(I see a function triggered). The second problem Is that I want on every reload the value (true or false) to be returned and set to the checkbox. How to fix this issues?

```
     TimeSch(localStorage.getItem("'TimeSch'"));
        function TimeSch(a) {
            if (a) {
                document.getElementById('TimeSch').checked = 'true';
                console.log('True start');
                Set('TimeSch', true);
                $('#theme').prop('disabled', true);
                const hours = new Date().getHours();
                const isDayTime = hours > 6 && hours < 20;
                if (isDayTime) {
                    theme('White');
                    console.log('Auto White');
                } else {
                    theme('Dark');
                    console.log('Auto Dark');
                }
            } else {
                 document.getElementById('TimeSch').checked = 'false';
                    console.log('False start');
                $('#theme').prop('disabled', false);
                Set('TimeSch', false);
            }
        }
  function Set(name, value) {
        if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("'" + name + "'", value);
        } else {
            console.log('No localStorage supported. Oh, please chage your browser!');
        }
    }
```

https://codepen.io/abooo/pen/PVQaWB

Comment: localStorage only stores Strings.  So it's most likely storing a string of true or a string of false.  Both strings being truthy.

Comment: Also do not use `Set` to name your variables or functions (especially in global scope), as it is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: I tried Taplar's idea of changing the bools with strings but this seems to be only part of the problem and not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, on line 4 and line 18 use boolean

```
document.getElementById('TimeSch').checked = true;
```

Secondly, you don't need to add quotes for localStorage keys. Simply do:

```
localStorage.setItem(name, value);

localStorage.getItem("TimeSch")
```

Finally the problem is line 3: The value coming from localStorage is string, so the condition will always be true. Change this to:

```
if (a === "true" || a === true)
```

and it should work.

Link to these changes: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dadjGq?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code snippet:

- there's no implementation of the `theme()` function
- `input[type="checkbox"]` is inside of the `select` element, which is invalid markup, also they get enabled/disabled simultaneously
- css for `input[type=checkbox]:after` doesn't take into account the state of the checkbox, so it always will show only `x`
- to set the property of the element you do not need `jQuery`
- to check the checkbox through JS you should give it `Boolean`, not the string
- why would you do this: `localStorage.setItem("'" + name + "'", ...`? consider using: `localStorage.setItem(name, ...` directly

It is still not clear what you are trying to achieve in general, but I made some patches and at least it got somewhat alive: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdQEvr